# Ayuda con comparacion entre dos arrays en JAVA

Tags: java

```
 public boolean hayRepetidos(){
    for (int i=0; i<m.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<m.length; j++){
             if (m[i]==m[j])
                    }                       
              }
            }
```

Hola gente estoy aprendiendo JAVA, e hice un ejemplo en donde tengo que comparar dos arrays (numericos) y devolver True si hay algun numero repetido y en caso contrario devolver False.

Creo que la comparacion entre Arrays está lista pero como puedo mostrar True y False en cada caso?
El main está en otro archivo y ahí está listo para mostrar la respuesta con la ayuda de este codigo.

PD: m, es mi arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el problema solo consiste en saber si al menos algún dato cualquiera se repite en ambos arreglos, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente.

```
public class Ejemplo {

   //Puedes colocar los números que quieras en los arreglos
   static int arreglo1 = {10, 15, 20, 25, 30}; 
   static int arreglo2 = {15, 20, 45, 50, 55};

   public boolean hayRepetidos(){
      boolean datosRepetidos = false;
      for (int i=0; i<arreglo1.length; i++){
         for (int j=0; j<arreglo2.length; j++){
             if (arreglo1[i]==arreglo2[j])
                 datosRepetidos = true;
                 break; //Rompe la iteración puesto que, si determinó que un dato se repite, no es necesario seguir comparando.   
             }                       
         }
      } 
      return datosRepetidos;
   }
}
```

En el método principal (que de acuerdo a lo que comentas, lo tienes en otra clase):

```
public class Principal{
   public static void main (String args []){
      Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo(); //Instancia de la clase donde se encuentra tu método hayRepetidos()
      boolean respuesta = ejemplo.hayRepetidos(); //Obtener el valor que retorna el método.
      if(respuesta){ //Determina que mensaje mostrar en función de la respuesta que devolvió el método.
          System.out.println("Hay datos que se repiten en los arreglos");
      }else{
          System.out.println("No hay datos repetidos");
      }
   }
}
```

La anterior solución solo permite saber si al menos un dato se repite, más no cuales y cuántas veces. Espero que resuelva tu duda.

Comment: amigo me funcionó tu codigo ya que ahora no me un error que tenía, pero cometí un error al hacer mi pregunta, el cual es que el array que estoy comparando es el mismo. Ejemplo:
arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5,5]
debo saber si dentro de ese mismo arreglo se repite algun numero, en este caso, se repite el 5 por ejemplo por lo que la respuesta seria True.

Comment: @FernandoYañez Ya realice algunas modificaciones al código, checalas, ya agregué dos arreglos diferentes. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos podrias usar el  **Arrays.equals**:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3}; 
        int arr2[] = {1, 2, 8}; 
        if (Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)) 
            System.out.println("IGUALES"); 
        else
            System.out.println("NO IGUALES"); 
  }
}
```

Te sugiero revisar lo siguiente para mas detalle:

[java.util.Arrays.equals](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_equals_object.htm)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está un ejemplo de la comparación para determinar si un número está repetido en un mismo array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list1 = { 1, 6, 8, 8, 4 };

    numeroIgual(list1);
}

public static void numeroIgual(int[] list1) {
    boolean existe = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= list1.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= list1.length - 1; j++) {
            if (list1[i] == list1[j]) {
                existe = true;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(existe);
}
```

En este caso te daría **true**, porque se repiten dos números 8 dentro del array list1, deberías reformular la pregunta con el nuevo requerimiento que se escribió en el comentario